# How to make iso image in Ubuntu linux that booted from live usb?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, boot, iso-image

How to make an iso image in Ubuntu 12.04 linux that booted from live usb?

The normal way as I understand is to use `dd`:

```
umount /dev/cdrom
dd if=/dev/cdrom of=/media/EOS_DIGITAL/snow_leopard_cd_bydd
```

However, `/cdrom` in live usb doesn't refer to optical drive, 
so is there a way to make an iso image of the CD drive using `dd`? What should I put in `dd` then?

I have found that it mounted in on `/dev/sr0`, but will `dd` produce a proper iso image if I use `/dev/sr0` instead of `/dev/cdrom`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `/dev/sr*` should be the same as `/dev/cdrom`. `/dev/cdrom` is often a symbolic link to the appropriate subsystem's device name.

More technical information on the cdrom driver [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-2.4-HOWTO/sr.html). More on device drivers [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-2.4-HOWTO/ulevel.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **unetbootin** tool (*apt-get install unetbootin*).